# Set url pattern to catch all urls like /messages?inbox or /list?orders

Tags: java, url-pattern

i am new to java and i have faced to very strange problem with url mapping...

i have to write a url pattern to catch the urls like:

XX/../list?inbox

../action?SomeAction

.. - means anything.

i need such a configuration in my web.xml file, somewhere near:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ajax</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test the strings:

```
url.endsWidth("/list?inbox");
url.endsWidth("/action?SomeAction");
```

Comment: sorry, i think you didn't get me right :) i need to map such a urls in web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

what about following URL pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

It just matches every URL withing your context

Comment: in this case all other pages, css styles, image files and any other resources on the server will be forbidden. HTTP Status 404